# Adding new data to Adapter affects initial values

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to build a simple chat interface. When a user click `enter` their message is sent to the server, added to the DB and simultaneously inserted into the `MessageAdapter` that's on the client's device so it appears on their screen.

Messages from the user are right-aligned and vice-versa for non-users.

When a user sends a message, as opposed to all the messages shifting up one spot, the text shifts up but not the actual message objects.

I'm trying to have a user send a message and all previous messages effectively shift up so the new message can appear below.

[image: Original message structure]

[image: Post-message sent structure]

Initially the non-user message is `Hello` but after I send the user's message, the message below the non-user, `Hey` takes its place.

This is my code for the `MessageAdapter`:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

List<Message> data= Collections.emptyList();
List<Integer> message_type= Collections.emptyList();

// create constructor to initialize context and data sent from MainActivity
public MessageAdapter(List<Message> data, List<Integer> message_type) {
    this.data=data;
    this.message_type=message_type;
}

public void addItem(Message item, int message_type){

    this.data.add(item);
    this.message_type.add(0, message_type);

}

// Inflate the layout when ViewHolder created
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_non_user, viewGroup, false);
            return new ViewHolder0(v);
        case 2:
            View q = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_user, viewGroup, false);
            return new ViewHolder1(q);
    }
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_non_user, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder1(v);
}

// Bind data
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 0:
            ViewHolder0 viewHolder0 = (ViewHolder0)viewHolder;
            Message current0 = data.get(position);
            viewHolder0.body.setText(current0.message);
            break;

        case 2:
            ViewHolder1 viewHolder1 = (ViewHolder1)viewHolder;
            Message current1 = data.get(position);
            viewHolder1.body.setText(current1.message);
            break;
    }
}

// return total item from List
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int temp = message_type.get(position);
    if(temp == 0 ){
        return 0;
    }
    return 2;

}
class ViewHolder0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView body;

    public ViewHolder0(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        body = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_body);
    }
}

class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView body;

    public ViewHolder1 (final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        body = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_body);

    }
}
}
```

And then this is the code for the `send-message action`:

```
 Message user_input = new Message();
 user_input.message = chat_input.getText().toString();
 messageAdapter.addItem(user_input, 0);

 messageAdapter.notifyItemInserted(messageAdapter.getItemCount()+1);

 MessagesRecyclerview.scrollToPosition(messageAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
 messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 chat_input.getText().clear();
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because you are adding your data like this:

```
this.data.add(item);
this.message_type.add(0, message_type);
```

you are adding your types at the begining of the list but you are adding your data at the end of the list, so it looks like there is a shift in your data.
use this:

```
this.data.add(0,item);
this.message_type.add(0, message_type);
```

Or this:

```
this.data.add(item);
this.message_type.add(message_type);
```

Comment: Ah! So obvious, thank you very much :) The second option worked. When I used the first there was no visible change which I think came from ".scrollToPosition(messageAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);"